# Python Pylab - set 3d text color

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, graph, 3d

I have a 3d plot in Python Pylab:

```
import numpy
import pylab
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as axes3d

img = Image.new('L', (60, 40), 255)
drw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 20)
drw.text((5, 1), 'TEXT', font = font)

X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(range(60), range(40))
Z = 1 - numpy.asarray(img) / 255

fig = pylab.figure()
ax = axes3d.Axes3D(fig)
ax.plot_surface(X, -Y, Z, rstride = 1, cstride = 1)
ax.set_zlim((0, 50))

fig.show()
```

[image: 3d plot]

How can I make the text (and only the text, not the entire graph) a particular color?

I've tried using the `fill` and `stroke_fill` arguments but they don't seem to do anything.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a predefined colormap (`viridis` in this example) with the `plot_surface` command.

```py
ax.plot_surface(X, -Y, Z, rstride = 1, cstride = 1, cmap='viridis')
```

Or, alternatively, you can create your own [`colormap`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.4/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html#creating-colormaps-in-matplotlib) adjusting the `vmax` parameter and the length of the colormap to achieve the desired output.

```py
...
...
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as axes3d

from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
colors=["gray", "black"]
cmap = ListedColormap(colors)

img = Image.new('L', (60, 40), 255)
...

ax.plot_surface(X, -Y, Z, rstride = 1, cstride = 1, cmap=cmap, vmin=0, vmax=0.1)
...
...
```

[image: viridis_plot] [image: listedcolor]